# How can you picture Conditional Probability in a 2D Venn Diagram?

Tags: probability, intuition, visualization

<sub>I already read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/294613/53259), and so wish to intuit 3 without relying on (only rearranging) the definition of Conditional Probability.</sub>

I pursue only intuition; do not answer with formal proofs.

Which region in my 2D Venn Diagram below matches $Pr(A|B)$?
On the left, the green = $\Pr(A\cap B)$. The right is [herefrom](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/t6G8mL0w4xM/hqdefault.jpg), but fails to indicate or specify $Pr(A|B)$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following answers your explicit question:  "Which region in my 2D Venn Diagram matches $Pr(B|A)$?"

No single region within the diagram corresponds to $Pr(B|A)$.  Instead, $Pr(B|A)$ is the ratio of the green region to the full region of $A$.  This term is read:  "The probability that $B$ is the case *given that A is the case*.  So... read that phrase "backwards":  Given $A$ is the case means you're restricted to be within the disk labeled $A$.  Now that you're in that disk, *what is the probability that you are within B*?  That is the ratio of the area of the green region to the area of all of $A$.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the confusion; you are editing faster than me!