# Why is $p(x_1 \mid x_2) \neq p\Big((x_1,x_2)\Big)$?

Tags: probability

Say we have a discrete random variable: $$\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2\end{bmatrix}$$ which has probability mass function of (here variates $x_1$ horizontal, $x_2$ vertical):

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,3))=0.09 | p((2,3))=0.03 | p((3,3))=0.06 | p((4,3))=0.12 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,2))=0.20 | p((2,2))=0.00 | p((3,2))=0.05 | p((4,2))=0.25 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,1))=0.01 | p((2,1))=0.07 | p((3,1))=0.09 | p((4,1))=0.03 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Why is $p(x_1=1 \mid x_2=2) \neq p\Big((x_1=1,x_2=2)\Big)$? I do understand manthematically why the values are different.
$$p\Big((x_1=1,x_2=2)\Big) = 0.2$$
From what is sometimes called the 4th (conditional) axiom of probability:
$$p(x_1=1 \mid x_2=2) = \frac{p\Big((x_1=1,x_2=2)\Big)}{p(x_2=2)}=\frac{p\Big((x_1=1,x_2=2)\Big)}{p(x_1,x_2=2)} = \frac{0.2}{0.5} = 0.4$$
$$0.2 \neq 0.4$$

I do not have an intuitive understanding though and perhaps a better question would be: **what is the meaning of $p(x_1=1 \mid x_2=2)$ here?**

Comment: Hint: google conditional probability, e.g.: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294580/intuition-behind-the-definition-of-conditional-probability-for-2-events

Comment: It means, if $x_2 = 2$ is _known_ to have occurred, what is the probability of $x_1=1$, _given_ that information. Note some pairs in the original sample space are no longer possible. Effectively, this creates a new sample space with only the pairs having $x_2=2$. For the reduced set of pairs, all probabilities are scaled so the the sum is equal to $1$ (so ratios of probabilities are left unchanged).

Comment: You actually wrote $p(x_{1}=1 | x_{2}=2) = \frac{p\Big((x_{1}=1,x_{2}=2)\Big)}{p(x_{2}=2)}$, to have $p(x_{1}=1 | x_{2}=2)= p\Big((x_{1}=1,x_{2}=2)\Big)$, you need $p(x_2=2)=1$, isn't?

Comment: You called your two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ but then changed their names without notice to $x_1$ and $x_2.$

Comment: @Michael Hardy $X_{1}$  -- variable, $x_{1}$ -- variate (i.e. element of a set of the range the variable takes).

Comment: The equality $$\frac{p\Big((x_1=1,x_2=2)\Big)}{p(x_2=2)}=\frac{p\Big((x_1=1,x_2=2)\Big)}{p(x_1,x_2=2)}$$ doesn't make sense. I'm going to go back to your original notation and call the two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ rather than $x_1$ and $x_2$. You have $$ \begin{align} & \frac{p\Big(X_1=1\ \&\ X_2=2\Big)}{p(X_2=2)} \\  \\ = {} & \frac{p\Big(X_1=1\ \&\ X_2=2\Big)}{p\Big((X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=1) \text{ or } (X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=2) \text{ or } (X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=3) \text{ or } (X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=4)\Big)} \end{align} $$ and then you have a sum of four numbers in the denominator.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger : My comment stands. You can say $\Pr(X_1 = x_1) = \text{some specified function of } x_1,$ and that's where the difference between $X_1$ and $x_1$ matters. But to say $\Pr(x_1 = 1)$ is nonsense.

Comment: @quasi Thanks -- I find it helpful to think of it as new sample space being created (it is sort of rescaling of probability to fit that reduced sample space). But then, how can you really reduce sample space (or range) of a bivariate variable?

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger : The way you reduce it is by observing that $X_2=2. \qquad$

Comment: @quasi I think the easiest (although perhaps contrived) way for me to think about this is that conditionality is almost like an operator that acts on my probability (mass) distribution $p_{\mathbf{x}}$ to (in an almost Bayesian sense) to reshape and rescale my probability distribution using prior information.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional probability is like imagining both events, $x1$ and $x2$ have already happened. In fact, imagine them being tried a lot of times. Then, $p(x_{1}=1|x_{2}=2)$ is simply the probabilty of $x1$ being one out of all tries where $x2$ was equal to two. This can be seen in the 'axiom' you gave (which to me is more of a definition), where you take all instances where it $(1,2)$ "happened" over all the ones where $x2$ was equal to two.

Another helpful way of thinking of it is its name: *conditional*. What are the odds of $x1$ being 1 *on the condition of* $x2$ being a two? That's what the conditional probability is, it is a measure of probabilty defined over a condition.

Finally, it's also interesting to take a step back on that last sentence, and realize that a conditional probability works with an even $A$ and not always a simple equality. For example, $p(x_{1}=1|x_{2}>2)$ and, more generally, $p(x_{1}=1|A)$ are both perfectly valid conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go back to your original notation and call the two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ rather than $x_1$ and $x_2$. You have
\begin{align}
& \frac{p\Big(X_1=1\ \&\ X_2=2\Big)}{p(X_2=2)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{p\Big(X_1=1\ \&\ X_2=2\Big)}{p\Big((X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=1) \text{ or } (X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=2) \text{ or } (X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=3) \text{ or } (X_2=2\ \&\ X_1=4)\Big)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{0.2}{0.2 + 0 + 0.05 + 0.25} = \frac{0.2}{0.5} = 0.4.
\end{align}

What this means is that you're narrowing the probability space down to the one row in the table in which $X_2 = 2.$ That row is:
$$
0.2, \quad 0, \quad 0.05, \quad 0.25
$$
Forty percent of the probability in that row is in the first entry. So when you're given that $X_2$ turned out to be $2$ is in that first entry.

Answer (score 0):

The reason $p(x_{1} \, | \, x_{2} ) \neq p\big((x_{1}, \, x_{2})\big)$ is because the **probability mass functions are no longer the same**. The conditional notation is slightly confusing implying that it has something to do with the variable -- it has only little (in that only the domain that meets the condition remains) -- but more importantly probability is rescaled.

Let me illustrate. The original question has probability mass function $p_{\mathbf{X}}$ where $\mathbf{X}$ is a 2-tuple $(X_{1},X_{2})$.

The exact details are given by the table:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,3))=0.09 | p((2,3))=0.03 | p((3,3))=0.06 | p((4,3))=0.12 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,2))=0.20 | p((2,2))=0.00 | p((3,2))=0.05 | p((4,2))=0.25 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,1))=0.01 | p((2,1))=0.07 | p((3,1))=0.09 | p((4,1))=0.03 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

What happens is that conditionality acts like an operator (sorry for the contrived notation) $\boxed{\big|x_{2}=2}\big(p_{\mathbf{X}}\big)$, which (1) reduces the domain:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,2))=0.20 | p((2,2))=0.00 | p((3,2))=0.05 | p((4,2))=0.25 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

and (2) rescales the codomain to meet the second axiom of probability $p(\mathbf{X})=1$:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| p((1,2))=0.40 | p((2,2))=0.00 | p((3,2))=0.10 | p((4,2))=0.50 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

So if we were to call $p_{\mathbf{X}} = p_{1}$ and $p_{2} = \boxed{\big|x_{2}=2}\big(p_{1}\big)$ then yeah $p_{1} \neq p_{2}$; and so is $p_{1}\big((x_{1}=1,x_{2}=2)\big) \neq p_{2}\big((x_{1}=1,x_{2}=2)\big)$.